# Android cannot play Windows Media Encoder's HTTP video stream

Tags: android, video

I use Windows Media Encoder on a Win8 desktop to broadcast my webcam video stream as http://192.168.101.100:8080/ (in a pull manner). I can play this on another desktop within a same LAN with a desktop player.

The Android side code I use is as follows (in the `onCreate`):

```
    VideoView myVideo=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.my_video);
    String path1="http://192.168.101.100:8080";
    Uri uri=Uri.parse(path1);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    myVideo.setMediaController(mc);
    myVideo.setVideoURI(uri);
    myVideo.requestFocus();
    myVideo.start();
```

The permissions are given:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

The Android phone is also in a same LAN. But it reports "Cannot open the video". And the error in log is:

```
11-19 15:05:12.114: I/MediaPlayer(3410): setDataSource(http://192.168.101.100:8080)
11-19 15:05:12.144: E/MediaPlayer(3410): error (1, -1004)
11-19 15:05:12.144: W/MediaPlayer(3410): info/warning (1001, 0)
11-19 15:05:12.169: E/MediaPlayer(3410): Error (1,-1004)
```

What is the reason for this problem?